# Choosing free variables for matrices in RREF

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently reading this online LibreText book on Linear Algebra by David Cherney, Tom Denton, & Andrew Waldron.

In chapter 2.1 about Gaussian Elimination, it is written the following:

> The last example demonstrated the standard approach for solving a system of linear equations in its entirety:
>
> - Write the augmented matrix.
> - Perform EROs to reach RREF.
> - **Express the non-pivot variables in terms of the pivot variables.**

However, in the example, the author seems to do exactly the opposite:
[Example 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8NRS.png)

And then, the author says the following:

> There are always exactly enough non-pivot variables to index your
> solutions. In any approach, the variables which are not expressed in
> terms of the other variables are called free variables. The standard
> approach is to use the non-pivot variables as free variables.

Therefore, I believe that the pivot variables should be expressed in terms of non-pivot variables, according to what I observe.
Could someone confirm this?

Comment: Yes, you are correct: the actual step here is to express pivot variables in terms of non-pivot variables.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, I was not sure about it.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Could you explain the following proposition?

"In general, all solutions can be written in terms of the free variables. In
 with $j>i$. This leads to the following observation.

Proposition 1.4.1: Basic and Free Variables
If $x_i$ is a basic variable of a homogeneous system of linear equations, then any solution of the system with $x_j=0$ for all those free variables $x_j$ with $j>i$ must also have $x_i=0$."

Comment: For example, suppose that $x_1$ is a basic variable and that $x_2,x_3,x_4$ are all free varaibles. Then there are some coefficients $a_i$ for which our solution has the form
$$
x_1 = a_2 x_2 + a_3x_3 + a_4x_4.
$$
It follows that if we set these free variables equal to $0$, then the corresponding value of $x_1$ is $0$ because
$$
a_2(0) + a_3(0) + a_4(0) = 0.
$$
I hope that clarifies things

Comment: Oh I understand, thanks a lot. By the way, in the context of differential equations, I've seen homogeneous differential equations expressed several ways...
Some examples:
The equation has the form
1. $f(x,y)dx=g(x,y)dy$ 
2. $F(y/x)=dy/dx$
for first order eqs. Is there a relation between this and in linear algebra context?

Comment: There is a connection but it's a bit complicated. In brief: a linear system of equations can be expressed in the form $L(\mathbf x) = \mathbf b$, where $L$ is a [linear operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map), and this system is "homogeneous" when $\mathbf b = 0$. The same can be said for linear differential equations: there is a linear operator $L$ (for example, $L(y) = \frac{dy}{dx} + xy$) for which the equation of interest has the form $L(y) = f$, and the linear differential equation is called homogeneous when $f(x) \equiv 0$.